# SSh - Connect with different username

Tags: ssh

I am trying to connect to my university servers via my mac. The servers in question are as follows:

- `silo.soic.indiana.edu` and  `odic.cs.indiana.edu`

When I try using my username, I have no issue in connecting to both the servers and accessing my files. However i am trying to use my friends username (and password, provided by him), and I cant seem to connect to either of the instances. I googled the issues but there are no solutions that I have to work.

When I connect to the servers i use `ssh odin.cs.indiana.edu` and it automatically detects my username and prompts me with a password. After the password has been entered I am connected to the said instance.

For my friends username I use `ssh friend@odin.cs.indiana.edu` after which it prompts me for a password. When I enter the password, i get the return `Permission denied, please try again.` . I used the verbose `-v` argument to get more info into the process and I get this :

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to odin.cs.indiana.edu [129.79.240.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/isharief/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/isharief/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/isharief/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/isharief/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 55:49:2c:08:67:a9:f4:33:99:b1:3b:90:c5:c0:33:32
debug1: Host 'odin.cs.indiana.edu' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/isharief/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/isharief/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/isharief/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

AFter which I enter the password and I get permission denied. both of us have extremely low skills regarding `ssh` , `keys` etc so can someone please give a simple explanation /workaround for this issue?

Comment: A possible workaround may be to execute `su friend` to switch user name to that of your friend...  if they are so kind or ahem stupid as to give out their password(s) and then `cd` to his home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to log in as you because in the remote server's /home/you/.ssh/authorized_keys your public key is present but it is not there in /home/yourfriend/.ssh/authorized_keys. You need to add the public key to the /home/yourfriend/.ssh/authorized_keys. You can try the following

```
ssh-copy-id -i yourkey.pub yourfriend@servername
```

It adds the public key to the /home/yourfriend/.ssh/authorized_keys. But you need your friend's password which he uses to log in to the server. if it doesn't work you need to manually append the key to the /home/yourfriend/.ssh/authorized_keys. If you are manually appending make sure you are appending the key as one single line.

hope it helps. It might resolve the issue but you still can face issues because of the sshd_config file on the remote server. Try the above method and let me know if you are still facing any issue.